# how GET method is idempotent

Tags: servlets, post, get

How GET method is idempotent and POST is not. we are using it in form submission, if we submitting it twice it will re-submitting the form data's. And why we are not using GET for order placing or purchasing products for instance when it is idempotent.

Answer (score 0):

An **idempotent HTTP method** is a HTTP method that can be called many times without different outcomes. It would not matter if the method is called only once, or ten times over. The result should be the same. Again, this only applies to the result, not the resource itself.

```
 a=10;  //This is idempotent: no matter how many times we execute this statement, a will always be 4. 
 a++;  //This is not idempotent. Executing this 10 times will result in a different outcome as when running 5 times.
```

Now, coming to your query.
If we use GET method for order placing/purchasing products, the order will be placed no matter the product is gone out of stock. In contrast if you use the to POST method the result will be different for each new request made for purchasing product.

Below example is not idempotent because for every new request the outcome will be different

```
https://accounts.google.com/Login#identifier
```

The GET method should be used to send the information from the browser to the server in the **URL**. Below is an example usage of GET method.

```
http://www.google.co.in/search?q=cristiano+ronaldo
```

**Below is the answer to your query in the comments:**

When users revisit a page that resulted from a form submission, they might be presented with the page from their history stack (which they had probably intended), or they might be told that the page has now expired. Typical user response to the latter is to hit Reload.

This is harmless if the request is idempotent, which the form author signals to the browser by specifying the GET method.

Browsers typically will (indeed "should") caution their users if they are about to resubmit a POST request, in the belief that this is going to cause a further "permanent change in the state of the universe", e.g. ordering another Mercedes-Benz against their credit card or whatever. If users get so accustomed to this happening when they try to reload a harmless idempotent request, then sooner or later it's going to bite them when they casually [OK] the request.

Now, while implementing those two methods GET and POST, a developer should consider the security issues and write the code in the particular method. Any code can be written in both the methods considering all the limits of GET method(size of url etc.), But this is not a good practice.

GET -> for information retrieval.(If you want to read data without changing state)
POST -> for information creation/updation/deletion.

Comment: In GET method if we place the order twice like refreshing or go back and click the submit button again what will happen. Will it place twice or only one time.

Comment: try this first by yourself.

Comment: I tried but I could not get the exact solution. If u dont mind can you give an example for GET and POST which will reflect idempotent

Comment: Yes, sure. But right now i'm busy with some other assignments. will get back to you soon.

Comment: No problem carry on, but come back when you are free I need help.